# Unable to embed external widget in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Trying to add an external JavaScript widget with the  tags to my WordPress footer's widget area but at present only get a blank area.

I have tried using `enhancedtextwidget` to put the code in, but it makes no difference.

I can't seem to find a working answer to this so far, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out an answer.

Had to put

`<script>var $ = jQuery.noConflict();</script>`

ahead of it and it works.